# Unit test in Xcode 7 requires rebuilding of code

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xcode7

In Swift (using Xcode 7), when I create my unit test, it requires that I rebuild my source project every time I make a change to it in order for the unit test to pick up new methods that have been added.  This was not the case with Objective-C.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you adding your application source files to the test target? This is the most likely reason this is happening. So for instance, if you have two classes, e.g. SolarPosition and SolarPositionTest, each should only be in the respective targets, the app and test targets.

This has been debated at various times. For sure, you are not supposed to have to add either source to tests or tests to source targets.

Incremental building in Xcode makes it the fastest test platform I have ever used by a mile. It never has to rebuild for test changes.

Comment: Good catch, it didn't get added.

Comment: I find that even if I add a new swift to the target membership, I still need to build it at least once for it to be picked up.  Subsequent changes to the file will get picked up.

Comment: but that makes sense no? I know I was adding source to test targets way back because the import process was a mess, but in Swift, if you import or do @testable import <module> you are pretty much covered...